# Touchpad becomes very jerky and other problems on ubuntu 17.10

Tags: touchpad, dell, 17.10, libinput

I recently install ubuntu budgie 17.10. I found that it uses libinput which is fairly good compared to synaptics input, but still I found these issues which are really very annoying:

1)Cursor is very jerky and erratic especially when I move my finger 
  diagonally on the touchpad.

2)Tapping sometimes does not work properly, until I tap towards the centre
  of the touchpad, and that too sometimes do not work!

3)The above issue also does not allow me to properly tap and drag to 
  select a long text, since I sometimes need to select a large chunk of 
  text and tapping is not detected.

Touchpad becomes fairly normal after sometime, but again become problematic after sometime!

PLS HELP!

Laptop: Dell Inspiron 3558

Linux: Ubuntu Budgie 17.10

xinput version: 1.6.2 (libinput)

XI version on server: 2.3

dmesg log specific to the touchpad(I guess!):

```
[    1.349295] rmi4_f01 rmi4-00.fn01: found RMI device, manufacturer: 
Synaptics, product: TM3096-001, fw id: 2019836
[    1.358534] fbcon: inteldrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    1.358586] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 170x48
[    1.358603] i915 0000:00:02.0: fb0: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
[    1.411711] input: Synaptics TM3096-001 as 
/devices/pci0000:00/INT3433:00/i2c-1/i2c-
DLL06B0:00/0018:06CB:78F1.0001/input/input7
[    1.411814] hid-rmi 0018:06CB:78F1.0001: input,hidraw0: I2C HID 
v1.00 Mouse [DLL06B0:00 06CB:78F1] on i2c-DLL06B0:00
```

cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep -i synaptics output:

```
28.475] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Synaptics TM3096-001 
(/dev/input/event7)
[    28.475] (**) Synaptics TM3096-001: Applying InputClass "libinput 
touchpad catchall"
[    28.475] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Synaptics TM3096-001'
[    28.475] (**) Synaptics TM3096-001: always reports core events
[    28.492] (II) event7  - (II) Synaptics TM3096-001: (II) is tagged by 
udev as: Touchpad
[    28.492] (II) event7  - (II) Synaptics TM3096-001: (II) device is a 
touchpad
[    28.493] (II) event7  - (II) Synaptics TM3096-001: (II) device removed
[    28.524] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Synaptics TM3096-
001" (type: TOUCHPAD, id 12)
[    28.524] (**) Synaptics TM3096-001: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[    28.524] (**) Synaptics TM3096-001: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    28.524] (**) Synaptics TM3096-001: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    28.526] (II) event7  - (II) Synaptics TM3096-001: (II) is tagged by 
udev as: Touchpad
[    28.526] (II) event7  - (II) Synaptics TM3096-001: (II) device is a 
touchpad
[    28.526] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Synaptics TM3096-001 (/dev/input/mouse0)
```

Comment: I've had the exact same problem since the update in October, and it still hasn't been fixed. Will try to switch back to the old input library.

Answer (score 1):

I unchecked Natural scrolling within Settings Touchpad and felt that the touchpad on my Dell laptop behaved less erratically (I'm a noob to Ubuntu so still getting to grips with all things Linux)